# Script to migrate contacts from Lotus Notes to Sharepoint and MailChimp

Tags: sharepoint, migration, lotus-notes, mailchimp

I want to write a piece of script/code to migrate contacts from Lotus Notes to Share Point and MailChimp. But I don't know where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: My first suggestion is to define your task more precisely. Is this a one-time task for your own contacts? Or do you need to run it for hundreds (or maybe thousands) of users? If it is the latter, will it be run by the actual users as needed, or will it be run in bulk by system administrators?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to migrate ALL contacts or have a filter?

You can export views from Notes into delimited or fixed width files (or even a spreadsheet) - you could then import into your system from that

Alternatively, if you want to script, you have the options of LotusScript/@functions/Java, with the obvious learning curve of the language AND the Notes Domain model